# Angular2 Get nested JSON data

Tags: angular

I am new to Angular2 and need a help.

I have a JSON file - https://api.myjson.com/bins/ctyoh

```
{
  "Semester": [
    {
      "queueName": "Science",
      "totalCount": 300,
      "unassignedCount": 10,
      "subjectDetails": [
        {
          "subjectName": "Chemistry",
          "sectionOne": 100,
          "sectionTwo": 50,
          "onTrackTradeCount": 150
        },
        {
          "subjectName": "Biology",
          "sectionOne": 100,
          "sectionTwo": 50,
          "sectionThree": 150
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "queueName": "Arts",
      "totalCount": 300,
      "unassignedCount": 10,
      "subjectDetails": [
        {
          "subjectName": "Indexing",
          "sectionOne": 100,
          "sectionTwo": 50,
          "sectionThree": 150
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "queueName": "Humanity",
      "totalCount": 300,
      "unassignedCount": 10,
      "subjectDetails": [
        {
          "subjectName": "Indexing",
          "sectionOne": 100,
          "sectionTwo": 50,
          "sectionThree": 150
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

How can I access `totalCount` of `Semester` &
`"subjectName": "Chemistry"` from a variable.
My Service is like this -

```
private url = 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/ctyoh'  

constructor(private http: Http) { }  
getData(): Observable<any> {  
return this.http.get(this.url)  
.map((res: Response) => res.json(),
```

I subscribe to the observable in the constructor of my Component like

```
constructor(private _chartData: ChartData) {}  
ngOnInit() {  
.subscribe(data => {  
this.data = data;  
console.log(data.Semester);  
});
```

Inside HTML I would like to render the value like this.
{{data?.Semester.totalCount}}
How can I do this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please post your JSON in your question, not as an external link.

Comment: I don't see anything even remotely matching `assetClassQueueDetails?.Credit[0].totalTradeCount` in your JSON. Please state the issue, what you have tried and where exactly you are facing an issue.

Comment: @AndreiMatracaru JSON is already there in the question.

Comment: @AJT_82 I just updated the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the total of `Semester` either by running a loop over it and adding all `totalCount` or if your array length is always fixed to 3, you can add them inside the interpolation too.

loop method:

```
for(let i=0; i< data.Semester.length; i++){
  this.grandTotal +=  data.Semester[i].totalCount;
} 

<p>Total: {{ grandTotal }}</p>
```

interpolation:

```
<p>Total: {{ data?.Semester[0]?.totalCount + data?.Semester[1]?.totalCount + data?.Semester[2]?.totalCount }}</p>
```

Accessing `Chemistry`:

```
<p>{{ data?.Semester[0]?.subjectDetails[0]?.subjectName }}</p>
```

[Plunker demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/QTVxFoO4EFlA5hsknjar?p=preview)

Answer (score 2):

You need a `ngFor` for displaying `totalCount` and a nested `ngFor` to show `subjectName`:

In service, extract the array:

```ts
getData(): Observable<any> {  
  return this.http.get(this.url)  
    .map((res: Response) => res.json().Semester) // extract the array
}
```

In component subscribe:

```ts
ngOnInit() {
  this.myService.getData()
    .subscribe(data => {
       this.data = data;
    })
}
```

Then you have the `ngFor`'s, which first iterates all objects in array, and then iterates the subarray `subjectDetails` in each object. Please notice the poor naming convention below. Change it fit your needs:

```html
<div *ngFor="let x of data">
  Total: {{x.totalCount}}
  <div *ngFor="let y of x.subjectDetails">
    Subject: {{y.subjectName}}
  </div>
</div>
```

DEMO: http://plnkr.co/edit/By1e12dOrat6D1myaP2E?p=preview